# What's the alternative of __declspec (naked)?

Tags: c++, masm, dll-injection

I'm learning dll injection these days. There is my code:

```cpp
__declspec(naked) void codecave() {
    __asm {
        pushad
        mov dword ptr ds : [ebx + 4] , 0xD
        popad
        mov dword ptr ds : [0x102AE98] , ebx
        jmp ret_address
    }
}
```

I used the key-word `__declspec (naked)` to avoiding the side-effect on stack(intend not to create stack frame). But When I tried to port it to x64, it was totally different.`__declspec (naked)` is disabled on x64. And I find inline assembly is also disabled on x64.

I find that I can use MASM to write assembly code. But what's the alternative solution of `__declspec (naked)` to avoid the side-effect on stack when making dll injection?

Comment: MS's docs state that it's only available on x86 and ARM, and do not offer an alternative for x64. Similarly, the `/Oy` optimization (to disable stack frames) also isn't available on x64.

Comment: If you write a separate .asm file you don't need the "naked" attribute, as that is the default for assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution! In VS2022 based on x64, we can install clang instead of the MSVC. Then we can use `_asm` to write inline assembly code. As for `naked` keyword. I find that we can use `__fastcall` to force the program to pass the first 2 params using registers instead of adding stack frame(but only first 2). By doing this we can avoid side-effect of dll injection!